# how to slice the text before after a particular word using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting the div's html value using JavaScript. it returns the value like

```
From looking down the Line, he turned himself about again, and, raising his eyes, saw my figure high above him.Without prolonging the narrative to dwell on any one of its curious circumstances more than on any other, I may, in closing it, point out the coincidence that the warning of the Engine-Driver included, not only the words which the unfortunate Signal-man had repeated to me as haunting him, but also the words which I myself—not he—had attached, and that only in my own mind, to the gesticulation he had imitated.
```

I need to slice the value before and after a particular text.unfortunate is that particular word.  For eg, i need to get like below

....Engine-Driver included, not only the words which the **unfortunate** Signal-man had repeated to me as haunting him, but also the words which I myself....

Comment: why do you want to do that

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'm searching a word in a div. ir returns it full content. i need to slice the content before and after that word

Comment: my question was after slicing what you want to do... do you want to highlight it

Comment: That might be a solution to the problem, but other than "I'm searching [for?] A word in a `div`" you've not explained what you need to do. There's almost certainly a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the updated comments, you need to highlight the word so you can use .replace() with a simple regex like

```
$('div').html(function(_, html){
    return html.replace(/(unfortunate)/gi, '<b>$1</b>')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pbH5C/)

Answer (score 3):

suppose your text is in divtxt then use this

```
var splitText=divtxt.split("unfortunate");
```

splitText[0] will have text before "unfortunate" and splitText[1] will have text after "unfortunate"

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of [indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) and [substring()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp). Find the index of the word unfortunate using indexOf("unfornate") and then substring using that index.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to split string considering comma(,) as a separator then you should do it like,

```
var yourString='From looking down the Line, he turned himself about again, and, raising his eyes, saw my figure high above him.Without prolonging the narrative to dwell on any one of its curious circumstances more than on any other, I may, in closing it, point out the coincidence that the warning of the Engine-Driver included, not only the words which the unfortunate Signal-man had repeated to me as haunting him, but also the words which I myself—not he—had attached, and that only in my own mind, to the gesticulation he had imitated.';

var arrResult=yourString.split(','); //this will return an array
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZdeC9/)**

Comment: @Jegadeesan ,after reading your  comment I would suggest that you should use  yourString.split('unfortunate') if you want to slice the string against 'unfortunate' word.

Answer (score 0):

if you want- "....Engine-Driver included, not only the words which the unfortunate Signal-man had repeated to me as haunting him, but also the words which I myself...."

```
var str = "From looking down the Line, he turned himself about again, and, raising his eyes, saw my figure high above him.Without prolonging the narrative to dwell on any one of its curious circumstances more than on any other, I may, in closing it, point out the coincidence that the warning of the Engine-Driver included, not only the words which the unfortunate Signal-man had repeated to me as haunting him, but also the words which I myself—not he—had attached, and that only in my own mind, to the gesticulation he had imitated."
    var i = str.indexOf('unfortunate');
    var j = str.indexOf('Engine');
    var k = str.indexOf('myself')
    var result = "..." + str.substring(j,i) + str.substring(i,k) + "...";
```